# Repeat with smaller steps than one

Tags: loops, applescript

So I have an Applescript `repeat with`-loop. It ranges from 1 to 10 and logs the number every time:

```applescript
repeat with i from 1 to 10
    log i
end repeat
```

This outputs something like this:

```
(*1*)
(*2*)
(*3*)
(*4*)
(*5*)
(*6*)
(*7*)
(*8*)
(*9*)
(*10*)
```

However, now I want `i` to go from 1 to 2 in steps of 0.1. Is there a built-in function to do that or do I have to work with a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the `repeat with from to` syntax but with `repeat while` and incrementing the *index variable* yourself

```
set i to 1.0
repeat while i ≤ 2.0
    log i
    set i to i + 0.1
end repeat
```

or go from 10 to 20 and divide i by 10

```
repeat with i from 10 to 20
    log i / 10
end repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, now I want `i` to go from 1 to 2 in steps of 0.1. Is there a built-in function to do that or do I have to work with a workaround?

From [repeat with loopVariable (from startValue to stopValue)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-128207)

**Syntax**

```
repeat with  loopVariable  from  startValue  to  stopValue [ by  stepValue ]

    [ statement ]...

end [ repeat ]
```

*stepValue*
           Specifies a value that is added to loopVariable after each iteration of the loop. You can assign an `integer` or a `real` value; a `real` value is rounded to an `integer`.

Default Value: 1

---

So when using `[ by  stepValue ]` this built-in function cannot do as you've expressed as is will always round a `real` to an `integer`.